# Is there a way in WooCommerce to display custom content after the product categories have displayed, but before the products?

Tags: woocommerce, categories

We're customizing the category pages and need to add a small bit of content directly after the product category / sub category list, but before the product list displays.

Essentially, we need to put some custom content between the calls for content-product_cat.php and content-product.php.  Just having an issue finding the specific area.

We've tried various hooks in the function template, but they put the content before or after the category / product loop has ran.

```
loop-start.php
content-product_cat.php
content-product.php
```

No errors, just need to locate the one spot where the category loop ends and the product loop begins.

Answer (score 0):

In our case we found that the break between the category and product loop was within the wc-template-functions.php file right after